# date() returns inconsistent time

Tags: php, datetime

I have the following PHP code on my local apache2 webserver on a Mac Book Pro using PHP 5.3.8 and Default timezone set to Europe/Zurich:

```
$now = time();
$in5min = $now + 300;

echo "now: " . date('H:m:s', $now);
echo "<br>in 5 min: " . date('H:m:s', $in5min);

echo "<br>now using date only: " . date('H:m:s');
```

Result looks like this (run at 18:16:12, 26 July 2012):

```
now: 18:07:01  
in 5 min: 18:07:01  
now using date only: 18:07:01
```

Note that I can refresh the page - the seconds change, the hours and minutes remain. So 5 minutes later it's still `18:07`.

What's wrong with my webserver settings? And why does the time calculation not work?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The correct format string is `i` for minutes, not `m`. [`m` is for months.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

```
date('H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong [`interval`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php), but I would suggest using [`DateTime::add`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) instead:

```
<?php
$date = date_create('2000-01-01');
date_add($date, date_interval_create_from_date_string('10 days'));
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Haha could hit me in the face: date('H:m:s') is totally wrong. "m" is for month, not minutes. Use date('H:i:s') instead