# PHP date & strtotime adding 12 minutes?

Tags: php

This code:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Stockholm');
$time = date('H:m', strtotime('08:00:00'));
echo $time;
```

Echoes `08:12`... why? what am I missing here?

Tried also online at http://writecodeonline.com/php/ with exact this code and got same result. I would expect a error in hours, in case I made something wrong, but 12 minutes seems very strange.

The `08:00:00` value is a example from my database, all times are stored as TIME.

Comment: possible duplicate of [date() returns inconsistent time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11673747/date-returns-inconsistent-time)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In date format **'m'** means month, not minutes. Try to use **'i'**.
For example:

```
$time = date('H:i', strtotime('08:00:00'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this. Your code has `m` which equals month & the resulting `12` is correct since it’s December. So you are looking for `i` which is minutes with leading zeros:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Stockholm');
$time = date('H:i', strtotime('08:00:00'));
echo $time;
```

Comment: Thanks Jake! my eyes are tired. Viktor answered first, some seconds... +1 to you too.